# onConfigurationChanged does not work

Tags: android

I want to listen the orientation changed

but it dose not work in SDK 4.0

and i found that the Manifest have to modify android:configChanges="orientation"

to android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

but it has an error :

[Screen Shot of Manifest](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/90416799/screen_shot2.png)

then i found that i do not have the option of "screenSize" in Manifest

[Screen Shot of config option in Manifest](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/90416799/screen_shot.png)

and the error message is

`error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'orientation|
 ScreenSize').`

what is wrong about my Manifest?

Comment: if you are building the app on 4.0 then the Manifest options exists, it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In manifest you have to add the below line. you had entered the wrong syntax that's why it is showing error.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Comment: No, the solution is building the app on 4.0